# Three20 navigation by openURLAction; self.navigationController is nil in pushed VC?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios4, three20

The navigation commences with `[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:theUrl];` from one UIviewController controller and another UIViewController is the target of that URL. The map is set with set with the following code and there is no doubt navigation goes to the right place:

```
TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
[map from:@"tt://goToMyViewController" toViewController:[MyViewControllerClass class]];
```

In the pushed view controller i want to manipulate the image on the Back button but don't want to change the title. It should always be the title of the view controller this one was pushed on top of, or localized "Back" if no title was set.

Problem:
In this pushed view controller's `viewDidLoad` I'm starting with

```
NSArray* viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
```

to get the navigation stack so I can look at the title of the appropriate view controller. But viewControllers is nil...

However if I do nothing the default back button does have the correct title. I thought of looking at the leftBarButtonItem and backBarButtonItem title properties but there is nothing meaningful there either...

Anyone know what is going on, why this is happening or how it can be worked around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those things where `viewDidLoad` is the wrong place to do it - after comparing various view controllers and finding no real difference in how they were invoked (yet had nil `viewControllers` while others didn't) it struck me that if it was really nil, `popViewControllerAnimated` shouldn't work either. I found `viewControllers` was NOT nil where I was calling `popViewControllerAnimated` and from there experiment showed I could get the title I was after in `viewWillAppear:`.
So, `viewWillAppear:` seems to be a reliable place to touch `self.navigationController` while `viewDidLoad` is not.

Comment: You know why now ? Strange behavior, isn't it ?